# extjs6 - grid contextmenu, pass through row selection

Tags: extjs, contextmenu

In my extjs6 project I have a grid, I want to add functionality to right click on grid, pick item from menu bar and launch pop up window, but passing row selection through to click method.

So far I have the right click menu bar working, but when clicking on menu item I want to pass through selected row from grid.  Can someone help me pass grid row selection to controller method?

my view

```
Ext.define('Example.ContextMenu', {
xtype: 'contextMenuMarketDrilldownAccount',
extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',
items: [{
    text: 'Market Drilldown by Account',
    listeners: {
        click: 'onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton2'
    }
}]
});

             //removing a lot of code to make it readable here
            xtype: 'grid',
            title: 'Details',
            itemId: 'detailsGridID',
            bind: {
                store: '{myDetailsStore}'
            },
            flex: 3,
            margin: '5px 0px 0px 0px',
            ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
            cls: 'custom-grid',
            height: '100%',
            collapsible: true,
            collapseDirection: 'left',
            listeners: {
                itemcontextmenu: 'showContextMenu2'
            },
```

CONTROLLER

```
    showContextMenu2: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    debugger;
    //var selectedMarket = rec.get('BBSymbol');
    this.getContextMenu2().show().setPagePosition(e.getXY());
    return false;
},

getContextMenu2: function () {
    if (!this.contextMenu) {
        this.contextMenu = this.getView().add({ xtype: 'contextMenuMarketDrilldownAccount' });
    }
    return this.contextMenu;
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem, change the block **this.getContextMenu2()** to **this.getContextMenu2(rec)**

```
showContextMenu2: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    debugger;
    //var selectedMarket = rec.get('BBSymbol');
    this.getContextMenu2(rec).show().setPagePosition(e.getXY());
    return false;
},

getContextMenu2: function (rec) {
    if (!this.contextMenu) {
        this.contextMenu = this.getView().add({ 
            xtype: 'contextMenuMarketDrilldownAccount',
            currentRecord: rec 
        });
    }
    return this.contextMenu;
}

//Then you catch a currentRecord on a contextMenuMarketDrilldownAccount component.
```

Comment: if I change my code to match yours, how do I catch currentRecord in the controller method 'onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton2'

Comment: OK, Follow the steps:

1. Set on showContextMenu2 the rec argument no a viewModel;
2. Then on method onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton2 you get viewModel property to current selected record.

Comment: that's the part I don't understand. how do I do.... 2. Then on method onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton2 you get viewModel property to current selected reco

Comment: I think I got it!      onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton2: function (item, e) {
        debugger;

        var menu = item.up('menu');
        var rec = menu.currentRecord;

Comment: Congrats! @solarissf